# Google keeps indexing /comment/reply URL

Tags: drupal

With the new update of Google algorithm called Penguin, I think my site was being penalized due to webspam. But of course I don't create post which seems to be spam to Google. It is just I think how Google index my site.

I found out that Google index the URL of my site like:

http://www.example.com/comment/reply/3866/26556

So there are so many comment/reply URL index by Google. I have already added:

Disallow: /comment/reply/ Disallow: /?q=comment/reply/

but still Google still index this URL.

Any idea how to prevent Google from indexing comments?

Comment: It would be easier to answer this if you posted a link to your site; otherwise it's hard to say more than "there's something wrong with your robots.txt that you need to fix".

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned *how long ago* you added those Disallow rules. The effect isn't instantaneous, requiring at the very least a wait until you're spidered again, and even then might take a bit longer for them to actually get removed from the index/results.

If you use Webmaster Tools, are they showing up in your "Crawler access" screen(under Site Configuration)? That'll at least give you an idea when the robots.txt file was last grabbed.

Comment: +1: This is a good point, and something I missed in my answer. If you didn't have those URLs disallowed before, just adding disallow rules for them in robots.txt doesn't make Google drop them from their index immediately. (In fact, they may never drop them, at least not if they keep seeing links to them on other pages.) However, disallowing the `/comment/reply` directory does mean that you can submit a [directory removal request](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=59819) for it through Google's Webmaster Tools.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that your [robots.txt syntax](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) is correct?  If you've signed up for [Google's Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/), you can use [their robots.txt testing tool](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449) to see how Googlebot interprets it, but there are also several third-party robots.txt syntax checkers on the web.

You can also add [robots meta tags](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93710) to your reply pages to stop search engines from indexing them.  One reason to do this, even if you have the pages disallowed in robots.txt, is that not all bots necessarily understand the fancier robots.txt syntax extensions such as `*` wildcards, or at least may not understand them the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [google webmaster tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools): site-configuration section -> site links in order to demote links on your website. You can also use robots.txt as suggested by Ilmari Karonen as well as configure .htaccess (or httpd.conf) to preform [301 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322454/syntax-for-301-redirect-of-www-to-non-www-using-httpd-conf)

Answer (score 0):

Using disallow in your robots file will not stop Google from indexing those links or pages. That only tells Google do not crawl them.

If those pages are linked to from other pages on your domain they still will index the pages.